# How to enqueue a job within a job dynamically in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, rails-activejob

I've a job, and when the job is run, at the very bottom of it, and I want to `enqueue` the same job again to run after 1 hour, but with different arguments.

What I've achieved so far:

```
class SimpleJob
  @queue = :normal

  def self.perform(start)
    puts "Right now, start = #{start}"
    start += 12
    time = some_request_external_api
    self.set(wait: time).perform_later(start)
  end
end
```

I'm using [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) gem, and running the job through `QUEUE=* rake resque:work`. Surely, it prints `Right now, start = 12` in beginning, but after that, nothing happens. How exactly can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than enqueuing the job again within itself, you could either use a scheduler, such as `clockwork`.

Or, if what you are trying to accomplish is in response to some event on another service, maybe you could look into it's documentation and see if it provides `webhook` functionality.

These would send `post` requests to your desired action whenever any action occurs on their side.

Comment: Good point, but here is the thing: I don't know in advance exactly when to schedule a job. I'd hit an external API, and in the response of that call, I'd decide when to run the very next job. So basically, I would like to have a functionality that lets me schedule jobs dynamically, instead of scheduling with pre-defined values.

Comment: If you are interacting with an API and said API allows you to set a webhook action to receive events, whatever action has occurred on their side, whether due to a call from your app or automatically, you should ideally receive the updated object via the webhook. Then you can trigger your job in this action instead. There would be no need to schedule it or enqueue it within itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for ways to setup recurring job. If thats the case, take a look at this:

https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler

Comment: I had a look at it, but what I want is something different. I want to run a job, and that job will run itself at the end. Could you include little bit of code for how would we accomplish the said functionality through resque-scheduler?